# ImportError: cannot import name 'abc' from 'bson.py3compat'

Tags: python, docker, pymongo, bson

I'm trying to install dependencies in Docker, related to `pymongo` and `bson`. But got the following error `ImportError: cannot import name 'abc' from 'bson.py3compat' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bson/py3compat.py)`.
I did add a specific version collected from requirments.txt but it doesn't help.
Here is `Docker` file (I'm installing and re-installing `bson` and `pymongo` as was suggested in some SO answer):

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/expresspart
EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install bson \
Inject==4.3.1 \
fastapi==0.62.0 \
motor==2.3.0 \
pydantic==1.7.3 \
pymongo \
starlette==0.13.6 \
uvicorn==0.13.1

RUN pip uninstall -y bson pymongo
RUN pip install bson==0.5.10 pymongo==3.11.2

COPY ./catalogue-api /app
CMD ["python", "/app/run_app.py", "--port", "5000"]
```

Full docker container log:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload
ok, port  5000
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 61, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 48, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 55, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 308, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 23, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 20, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/api_v1/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from api_v1.injections import base
  File "/app/api_v1/injections.py", line 2, in <module>
    from db.motor.file import IFileDAO, FileDAO
  File "/app/db/motor/file.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gridfs import NoFile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gridfs/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from bson.py3compat import abc
ImportError: cannot import name 'abc' from 'bson.py3compat' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bson/py3compat.py)
```

Comment: Why do you install specific versions of bson and pymongo to uninstall them and then install them again?

Comment: @BellyBuster, I don't know already, since nothing I was trying is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pymongo` installs a bson library so you don't need to install the `bson` module. If you revise your dockerfile as below this should work:

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/expresspart
EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install Inject==4.3.1 \
fastapi==0.62.0 \
motor==2.3.0 \
pydantic==1.7.3 \
pymongo==3.11.2 \
starlette==0.13.6 \
uvicorn==0.13.1

COPY ./catalogue-api /app
CMD ["python", "/app/run_app.py", "--port", "5000"]
```